# Open Modal View twice on iPad

Tags: objective-c, xcode, ios

Can I open a Modal View from an existing opened Modal View. Is this against apple's policy?

Comment: Yes you can open another without repercussions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it is possible to open a modal view from an existing modal view. I don't think it's against Apple policy. Apple does however state that a modal view should be used to break the flow:

> Use them to gather information from the user immediately.
>   Use them to present some content temporarily.
>   Use them to change work modes temporarily.
>   Use them to implement alternate interfaces for different device orientations.
>   Use them to present a new view hierarchy with a specific type of animated transition (or no transition)

If you want to show another modal view from an existing modal view, it would mean another flow which can be best put in a navigation controller.